# Carathéodory-measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

for the following task i need some help. Maybe someone can explain it to me.

thank you in advance for your efforts:).

(i)Show that, all $\lambda_*$ - Null sets $N \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ are Carathéodory measurable, i.e. that for all $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ $$\lambda_*(A)=\lambda_*(A \cap N) + \lambda_*(A \cap (\mathbb{R}/N))$$ is true.

(ii)Show that for $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$, $\mu_* = \lambda_*$ with $\mu_C$ from theorem $10.11$ holds:

$A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$  is Carathéodory-measurable if and only if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exist an open set $\mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ with  $A \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ such that
$$\lambda_*(\mathcal{O}/A) \le \epsilon.$$

- theorem 10.11:
  The sets of $\mu_*$-measurable sets forms a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}_C$ and $\mu_C$=$\mu_*|_{\mathcal{A}_C}$ is a measure on $\mathcal{A}_C$

**What I know:**

**the definition of a measure $\mu$:**

A measure on a measurable room $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ is a map $\mu:\mathcal{A} \to [0,1]$ with the following properties:

(i)  $\mu(\emptyset)=0$

(ii) Let $(A_i) \subset \mathcal{A}$ be a countable family of pairwise disjunct sets, then
$$\mu(\bigcup_i A_i)=\sum \limits_{i}\mu(A_i)$$

**the definition of an outer-measure $\mu_*$:**

An outer-measure on $\Omega$ is a map $\mu_*:\mathcal{P}(\Omega) \to [0,1]$ with the following properties:

(i)$\mu_*(\emptyset)=0$

(ii)(monotony) $A \subseteq B$ implies $\mu_*(A) \le \mu_*(B)$

(iii)($\sigma-subadditivity$) for countable families $(A_i)$ of subsets from $\Omega$ aplies that
$$\mu_*(\bigcup_i A_i) \le \sum \limits_{i}\mu_*(A_i)$$

**the definition of $\lambda_*$:**

- $\lambda_*(A)$ = inf {$\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N} } \vert Q_j \vert$ | $A \subseteq \bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}} Q_j $}

for (i) the following could be helpful:

- Let be $N \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ a Null set. Then for all $$\lambda_*(A \cup N)= \lambda_*(A)$$
  $\underline{proof}:$

It is valid with the monotonicity of the outer Lebesgue measure $$\lambda_*(A) \le \lambda_*(A \cup N) $$
since $A \subseteq A \cup N.$  Further applies because of the $\sigma$-subadditivity
$$\lambda_*(A \cup N) \le \lambda_*(A)  + \lambda_*(N) = \lambda_*(A)$$

for (ii) the following could be helpful:

- the identity A = B\(B\A)
- contruct a measurable B with the property $\lambda_*$(B\A)=0

**My Problems:**

(i)

- i dont know how I show the equation for all $\lambda_*$-Null sets

(ii)

- This task is difficult for me because I do not understand the equivalence described.
  I would appreciate an explanation of the equivalence and when this could be a useful tool

Comment: It is not clear what the outer measure $\mu_*$ is. Is it the outer measure induced by a measure $\mu$? If so, what is the measure $\mu$?

Comment: What have you tried for item (i) and item (ii)?

Comment: I have added in my post how $\mu$ and $\mu_*$ are defined. It is simply the $\mu$ and $\mu_*$ from the definition and not a specific measure/outer measure.            
To (i) I thought to show the equality , 
I have to show that $\lambda_*(A) \le \lambda_*(A \cap N) + \lambda_*(A \cap (\mathbb{R}/N))$ and $\lambda_*(A \cap N) + \lambda_*(A \cap (\mathbb{R}/N)) \le \lambda_*(A)$ holds true.

To (ii) I don't have anything yet on ....

Comment: You simply added the general definition of what is a measure and the general definition of what is an outer measure. In item (ii), what do you mean by "Show that.. $\mu_*=\lambda_*$?  Do you just want to prove that $\lambda_*$ satisfies the three conditions of being an outer measure?

Comment: (i) For all $\lambda_*$ - Null sets $N \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and  for all $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ 
$$ \lambda_*(A \cap N) =0$$
So
$$\lambda_*(A)\leq\lambda_*(A \cap N) + \lambda_*(A \cap (\mathbb{R}/N))\leq 0+ \lambda_*(A \cap (\mathbb{R}/N))\leq \lambda_*(A)$$ 
So
$$\lambda_*(A)=\lambda_*(A \cap N) + \lambda_*(A \cap (\mathbb{R}/N))$$